# Login author from wp-admin redirects to homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

I searched a lot about my problem and I did all ways. For example change `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` file, or change `site_url`, deactive theme and plugins. But all of them didn't solve my problem.

Just know the problem is from database, because, when sometimes I reset my WordPress, the problem dissapears. But I don't want to lose all my data and it is very hard to import all the data at once.

One thing I have doubt about that is I installed 1-2 manage users access plugins and did some changes, then deleted them. From that moment this problem happens and I can't find his solution. Just admin can join `wp-admin`, other users redirect to homepage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find and solved my problem.the problem was from wp_users_role field in wp_option table.I reset all roles there and problem fixed